# TeXShop on Mac: how to automatically run three times for Composition?

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, compiling, indexing, texshop

When I use the button "Composition" in **TeXShop**, I get a single pass compilation and all my references and index aren't right (I get ?? marks all over the PDF document instead of their proper number).  I know that I need *three runs* to get the references and index right.  I was using **Latexian** before, which had a preference option to automatically do 1, 2 or 3 runs at compilation (sadly, this great app is now defunct).  I don't see a similar option in **TeXShop**.  So how should I compile my document to get a PDF file with all references and index properly numbered?

Please, take note that I'm a full blown idiot and complete retard at Terminal programming and zsh coding/file management.  So I'm looking for a solution directly in **TeXShop**.

If there's no solution directly in **TeXShop**, despite all of its preferences options and settings, then how should a novice know that he need to do some pesky zsh/bash coding just to get a proper PDF file when he presses the Composition button?  I don't understand why **TeXShop** doesn't have this option in its fabulous preferences settings, like other old apps do have (**Latexian**, for example).

Comment: Greetings fellow physics teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the engines that come with TeXShop to automate your processing runs.

You didn't specify which version of TeXShop and TeX Live you are using so I will assume recent versions of both. In Finder, go to `~/Library/TeXShop` and you should see a folder named `Engines`. Open the `Engines` folder and you should see several files, some of which have names ending in `mk`. These are engines that use `latexmk`, a script that automatically processes your document the correct number of times so as to resolve references, create an index, etc. By default, you should see `lualatexmk`, `pdflatexmk`, and `sepdflatexmk` among the various files there (note that they all have the extension `.engine` if you have Finder configured to show extensions). If these files are in place, you are all set. If you do not see these files, open the folder named `Inactive` and then open the folder `Latexmk`. There you should see files described here. Just copy them up two levels to the `Engines` folder. Now quit and relaunch TeXShop.

On the main menubar, next to the `Typeset` button, you should see a dropdown menu. There should be an entry for each of the engines in the `Engine` folder described above. Select the one you need. If you want to process your document with pdfLaTeX (the usual default), you need to select `pdflatexmk`. Now when you typeset your document, the processing should continue until no more processing is necessary.

This is the "old" way. The more modern way is to put the line `!TEX program = pdflatexmk` at the top of your document and the corresponding engine will automatically be used.

Comment: Ahaa!  Thanks a lot!  I do have the files you mentioned.  I'm compiling right now to see if it all works...

Comment: By the way, is there a way in TeXShop to recompile automatically (3 times) in the preview window each time I type something in the source code, as I had in Latexian?  I guess not.

Comment: No. The engines do all the work because you don't always know in advance how many passes it may take.

Comment: Grrrr!  TeXShop halts the compilation with some "no file ..." in the console.  I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: This large document is compiling fine in Latexian and in Texifier (which I don't like much).  But not in TeXShop.

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't advise on what may be going on. If the topic of this question has been satisfactorily answered, you may need to open another question about why the document isn't compiling.

Comment: Ok, but one more question:  After quiting the app, TeXShop leaves a lot of useless files in my folder.  All other apps are deleting the temporary auxiliary files.  Is there a way to get the same with TeXShop?  It's a pain in the butt to get all these pesky auxiliary files ...

Comment: Sure. After compiling, you can either click "Trash Aux Files" on the Console window or select "Trash Aux Files" from TeXShop's File menu on the menubar. If there are still files leftover, you can configure TeXShop to delete them. Consult the documentation for how to do this, but note that it requires using Terminal.

Comment: Will I have to redo this operation (i.e trash ex. files) each time I compile a new document?  I would like to have this done automatically by default.

Comment: In general, yes, because many people (unlike you and me) like to keep them around because doing so apparently speeds up future compilations. Like you, I delete them when I'm satisfied with the final document. For the other thing, I edited the answer to show you how to always use the same engine.

Comment: So there's currently no way in TeXShop to automatically delete all the temporary aux. files, after closing the source code file?  Is that right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks alot for the help.  This is all clear.  I now need to fix the "no file ..." I get for my main document.  I don't understand this, since it's all compiling nicely with Latexian and Texifier.  I don't understand why it's now so complicated with TeXShop.

Comment: Different people have different workflows. When and if you post a new question about the new issue, be sure to include an example that we can compile to hopefully see the problem. It's so much easier to advise then.

Comment: Well, it will be difficult to me to give a specific MWE code of the issue, as the whole code is compiling fine in other apps, but not in TeXShop.  I don't understand why the compilation halts after a while, with "no file <name>" in TeXShop's console.

Comment: Note: if you hold the Opt key when you typeset Trash Aux Files is done before the typesetting.